# Get collection names with Spark connector MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any way to get the database collection names natively with the spark-connector.

Now i'm using pymongo to do it, but I wonder if is possible to do it with the spark connector.

My actual method, just for info:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().database
db_names = db.collection_names(False)

for name in db_names:
  spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/database." + name) \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/database." + name) \
    .getOrCreate()
...
```

Comment: With python the Mongo Spark Connector only uses the Spark API, so there is no native way to list collections.

Also, please note the SparkSession is a singleton, so when changing collections the configuration should be done on the `DataFrameReader` using the `option()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Ross 
I'll keep using pymongo but I will change my way of pointing to a different collection.
Put this comment as an answer so I could mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python the Mongo Spark Connector only uses the Spark API, so there is no native way to list collections.

Also, please note the `SparkSession` is a singleton, so when changing collections the configuration should be done on the `DataFrameReader` using the `option()` method.